# How to check if PostgreSQL installation supports SSL?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, centos

In the PostgreSQL documentation is described that required to build PostgreSQL for SSL support:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html

Is it possible that PostgreSQL installation supports SSL out of the box from some CentoOS repository?
How to check if PostgreSQL installation supports SSL?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213128) out.

Answer (score 8):

Pretty much any packaged PostgreSQL will support SSL.

That doesn't mean you can actually connect with SSL. For that, you need a private key and certificate to be configured for that install.

You really have:

- Is not compiled with SSL support
- Is compiled with SSL support but not configured for SSL
- Is compiled with SSL support and configured for SSL, but does not allow SSL connections in `pg_hba.conf` from my current location
- Is compiled with SSL support, configured for SSL, and `pg_hba.conf` allows (or requires) connections via ssl

The best way to see if it supports SSL, as a client, is to connect to it and see.

If you're checking to see if the server is compiled with SSL support, so SSL will work if you configure it, you can check `pg_config.h` from the development package; it will define `USE_OPENSSL` if it's enabled in the build. Or you can try to run the `postgres` executable with the `ssl=on` option set, e.g.

```
/path/to/postgres -c ssl=on
```

which will output:

```
FATAL:  SSL is not supported by this build
```

if SSL isn't available.